# can not apply where clause on column type timestamp whose name is "when"

Tags: sql, firebird

I have a table whose columns are `id(integer), emp_name(varchar2), when(timestamp)`. And I want to apply where clause on column named `WHEN`. I am trying to execute the query

```
select * from attendant where WHEN > 2016-04-28 10:05:30.0000;
```

But it is giving me error.

Comment: you can accept the answer, if your query is solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure `WHEN` is a reserved keyword so you have to escape it. Additionally, you have to put your datetime value inside `''`:

```
select * 
from attendant 
where "WHEN" > '2016-04-28 10:05:30.0000';
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `when` is reserved keyword used in `case` statement.
You can change your query like this

```
select * 
from attendant 
where `WHEN` > '2016-04-28 10:05:30.0000';
```

i.e use `tick` ( ` ) to quote the when.

or

```
select * 
from attendant 
where attendant.WHEN > '2016-04-28 10:05:30.0000';
```

i.e dot notation.

Comment: Column names need to be escaped with double quotes, not single quotes (nor back ticks).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel if escaped with back ticks, do we get error?

Comment: Yes, you'll get an error if you escape using backticks in Firebird.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel okay, that is interesting to know, I haven't used that yet, but command line, sqlyog, oracle, etc won't throw error for the same.

Comment: Oracle won't accept backticks either (it will return error _"ORA-00911: invalid character"_). You're thinking of MySQL as that is one of the few database systems that use the non-standard option of back ticks; the SQL standard specifies double quotes.